# Duration above a value analysis in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some time series data in Big Query, about 1M rows, each sample is per second. I'm looking to see how I can determine the time a value is above a given value. Like the weather / climate analysis when they say "30 consecutive days above 100F" is a new record. I'd also like to do the analysis for all values ie if this was weather data, consecutive days above a temp of X, where X is any value from, say, 0 to 100.

If this was in a spreadsheet and using representative values:

Data    Time    Power   220 Ramp function   Max

2   2019-11-02  6:44:06   192   0   0   5

3   2019-11-02  6:44:07   211   0   0
4   2019-11-02  6:44:08   226   1   1
5   2019-11-02  6:44:09   248   1   2
6   2019-11-02  6:44:10   221   1   3
7   2019-11-02  6:44:11   225   1   4
8   2019-11-02  6:44:12   233   1   5
9   2019-11-02  6:44:13   211   0   0
10  2019-11-02  6:44:14   234   1   1
11  2019-11-02  6:44:15   238   1   2

I set my threshold, in this example, at 220 in cell D1, then I see if the value in column C is >=220 and if it is I set the value of column D to be 1. The logic is

=if(C2>=D$1,1,0)

This continues for column D.

Then if the next row for column D is also 1, column E also increments. Thus column E ramps while column C is >=220, and then resets to 0 if column C <220. The logic is

=if(D2=1,D2+D1,0)

I'm looking to do this in BigQuery, because that's where the data is, and also I need a general solution that works for all values in column C.

I tried to do the table in HTML but its not working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(d = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY e ORDER BY b) e
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(e) OVER(ORDER BY b) e
  FROM (
    SELECT *, d != IFNULL(LAG(d) OVER(ORDER BY b), -1) e
    FROM (
      SELECT *, IF(c > 220, 1, 0) d
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  )
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (-- Data Time Power 220 Ramp function Max
  SELECT 2 a, TIMESTAMP '2019-11-02 06:44:06' b, 192 c UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2019-11-02 06:44:07', 211 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2019-11-02 06:44:08', 226 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '2019-11-02 06:44:09', 248 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '2019-11-02 06:44:10', 221 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, '2019-11-02 06:44:11', 225 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '2019-11-02 06:44:12', 233 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, '2019-11-02 06:44:13', 211 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, '2019-11-02 06:44:14', 234 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-02 06:44:15', 238 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(d = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY e ORDER BY b) e
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(e) OVER(ORDER BY b) e
  FROM (
    SELECT *, d != IFNULL(LAG(d) OVER(ORDER BY b), -1) e
    FROM (
      SELECT *, IF(c > 220, 1, 0) d
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
  )
)
-- ORDER BY b
```

with output

```
Row a   b                       c   d   e    
1   2   2019-11-02 06:44:06 UTC 192 0   0    
2   3   2019-11-02 06:44:07 UTC 211 0   0    
3   4   2019-11-02 06:44:08 UTC 226 1   1    
4   5   2019-11-02 06:44:09 UTC 248 1   2    
5   6   2019-11-02 06:44:10 UTC 221 1   3    
6   7   2019-11-02 06:44:11 UTC 225 1   4    
7   8   2019-11-02 06:44:12 UTC 233 1   5    
8   9   2019-11-02 06:44:13 UTC 211 0   0    
9   10  2019-11-02 06:44:14 UTC 234 1   1    
10  11  2019-11-02 06:44:15 UTC 238 1   2
```

> Update to address OP's comments below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (-- Data Time Power 220 Ramp function Max
  SELECT 2 a, DATE '2019-11-02' Date, TIME '06:44:06' Time, 192 Power UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2019-11-02', '06:44:07', 211 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2019-11-02', '06:44:08', 226 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '2019-11-02', '06:44:09', 248 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '2019-11-02', '06:44:10', 221 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, '2019-11-02', '06:44:11', 225 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '2019-11-02', '06:44:12', 233 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, '2019-11-02', '06:44:13', 211 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, '2019-11-02', '06:44:14', 234 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, '2019-11-02', '06:44:15', 238 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(e), 
  COUNTIF(d = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY e ORDER BY Date, Time ASC) e 
FROM ( 
  SELECT * EXCEPT(e), 
    COUNTIF(e) OVER(ORDER BY Date, Time) e 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT *, d != IFNULL(LAG(d) OVER(ORDER BY Date, Time), -1) e 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT Date, Time, Power, IF(Power > 220, 1, 0) d 
      FROM `project.dataset.table` 
    ) 
  ) 
)
-- ORDER BY Date, Time
```

with result

```
Row Date        Time        Power   d   e    
1   2019-11-02  06:44:06    192     0   0    
2   2019-11-02  06:44:07    211     0   0    
3   2019-11-02  06:44:08    226     1   1    
4   2019-11-02  06:44:09    248     1   2    
5   2019-11-02  06:44:10    221     1   3    
6   2019-11-02  06:44:11    225     1   4    
7   2019-11-02  06:44:12    233     1   5    
8   2019-11-02  06:44:13    211     0   0    
9   2019-11-02  06:44:14    234     1   1    
10  2019-11-02  06:44:15    238     1   2
```

Note: you can use any value in `IF(Power > 220, 1, 0)` expression!

Comment: Thanks for the SQL command. It gives me an error though "unrecognised name c"

Comment: you should use the fields' name that are in your table - have you tried? i didn't have them so named them in my example after spreadsheet columns you used in your question!

Comment: @SteveShiny - did you have chance to try?

Comment: Don't think its working quite right. If I set the threshold to 500, save the results as a new table, and then query that table, a selection of data is like this:
Row Date Time Power d e 
1 2019-06-06 05:18:20 146.0 0 2
2 2019-06-06 05:18:21 153.0 0 3

Comment: please clarify so I can double check - you were using same data as in my answer but changed threshold from 220 to 500 and result is not what you expected?

Comment: 1 - yes. 2 - 220 was an example value, I need to do this for arbitrary values from 350 to 1000. 3 - Correct

Comment: Here's the actual command:#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(d = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY e ORDER BY Date, Time ASC) e
FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(e), COUNTIF(e) OVER(ORDER BY Time) e
  FROM (
    SELECT *, d != IFNULL(LAG(d) OVER(ORDER BY Time), -1) e
    FROM (
      SELECT Date, Time, Power, IF(Power > 500, 1, 0) d
      FROM `dataset.table`
    )
  )
)

Comment: The actual table runs about 2.4GB with about 1M rows

Comment: Obviously 220 was an example and you can use whatever arbitrary value you need!!! I see no problem here. Have you tried to run example as it is in my answer? can you confirm it works as you would expected? meantime let me check you actual query (that you presented in your comment above) and than I will follow up with you! Btw. size and number of rows you mentioned is still small enough so it does not matter :o)

Comment: Ok. so two things: 1) in my example I am using column c that is TIMESTAMP (combined Date and Time) and 2)  you are definitely missing some using Date field in some of your ORDER BY expressions - thus the wrong result. Finally - see update in my answer - i adjusted sampled data to split timestamp to tow fields - date and time to match what looks like you have based on above comment!

Comment: Thanks for the adjusted command. I tried it, and still not working as expected. Here's a date extract that you can maybe have a go with bit dot ly slash shinysteve sorry can't do shortened URls only full URLs and a signed URl is too long!

Comment: i answered your original question - and it definitely works - sorry that you have some problem in actually adopting it! but it clearly works for the initial question you posted and I cannot help you more than I already did!